# JSON Schema with unknown property names

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to have a JSON Schema with unknown property names in an array of objects. 
A good example is the meta-data of a web page:

```
      "meta": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "unknown-attribute-1": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "unknown-attribute-2": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            ...
          }
        }
      }
```

Any ideas please, or other way to reach the same?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want to achieve

Comment: The meta-data is an array of object, where I don't know the possible names of the attributes of the objects

Comment: Which constraints do you want to enforce to your unnamed properties? Do you want them to have some type, or do you want their names to follow some pattern? You can have unknown property names in JSON schema provided you do not have additionalProperties=false

Comment: yes, I want to enforce them to be of type "string"
The names do not have to match any pattern

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848488/5663986) for a much much simpler way of achieving this compared to what suggested below.

Answer (score 137):

Use `patternProperties` instead of `properties`. In the example below, the pattern match regex `.*` accepts any property name and I am allowing types of `string` or `null` only by using `"additionalProperties": false`.

```
  "patternProperties": {
    "^.*$": {
      "anyOf": [
        {"type": "string"},
        {"type": "null"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
```

... or if you just want to allow a string in your "object" (like in the original question):

```json
  "patternProperties": {
    "^.*$": {
        {"type": "string"},
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
```

Comment: I'm getting error "Property 'patternProperties' is not allowed".

Comment: @AlexeySh. please post your full JSON and I will take look

Comment: exactly copypaste of your answer

Comment: @AlexeySh. my first guess would be if you're using JSON Schema or OpenAPI. If JSON Schema, then you should use a recent version. If OpenAPI, a bit of Googling shows patternProperties did not get into OpenAPI as of version 3. Maybe there's a later version.

Comment: it seems like because I was using swagger and it doesn't support the latest schema

Comment: this did work me, but without the `anyOf` and `additionalProperties` as well

Comment: Yes, there seems to be an extra pair of braces in the second example.

Answer (score 20):

You can make constraints on properties not explicitly defined. The following schema enforces "meta" to be an array of objects whose properties are of type string:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "meta" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "additionalProperties" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case you just want to have an array of strings, you may use the following schema:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "meta" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Solution of @jruizaranguren works for me. 
Though I am the same who defines the schema, i choosed another solution

```
"meta": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I converted the object to an array of name-value objects
An example of a valid JSON:

```
"meta": [
    [
      {
        "name": "http-equiv",
        "value": "Content-Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "content",
        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "value": "author"
      },
      {
        "name": "content",
        "value": "Astrid Florence Cassing"
      }
    ]
  ]
```