# In Postgres, how do I restrict JSONB to only allow `map[string]string`

Tags: postgresql

```
 CREATE TABLE test_labels (
   label jsonb;
 )
```

I have a table similar to this. The `label` comes as JSON from user input. The problem here is that I want to restrict `label` to be a string->string key-value map and not any other json strings.

Both of these input work and I want them to not work.

```sql
INSERT INTO test_labels (label) VALUES('["hi", "there"]')
INSERT INTO test_labels (label) VALUES('"hi there"')
```

I thought of limiting the jsonb to objects by adding a constraint

```sql
 CREATE TABLE test_labels (
     label JSONB,
     CONSTRAINT is_object CHECK (jsonb_typeof(label) = 'object')
 );
```

But this doesn't enforce `string->string`. i.e. I can insert `{"key": 28}` or `{"a": {"b": "c"}}`

---

I don't want to use `hstore` because the encoding/decoding works seamlessly with json inputs & also the labels come as json from users.
And having another table just to store labels seems overkill.

What are my options?

Comment: You may use JSON schema validation as a long term generic approach. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847903/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-key-value-pairs-in-json-schema) SO thread and  [this](https://github.com/gavinwahl/postgres-json-schema/blob/master/postgres-json-schema--0.1.1.sql) JSON schema validator for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Check that that all the values in your json object are of type string as well as ensuring that you get a json object.

One way to ensure this is to verify the length of the array of all string values in your json object equals the length of all the values in your json object.

The following is an extremely <s>ugly hack</s> advanced technique:

The jsonpath expression `'$.* ? (@ >= "")'` filters all strings and discards all non strings.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_labels (
  label jsonb
, constraint is_text_valued_object check ( 
      jsonb_typeof(label) = 'object' 
  and jsonb_array_length( jsonb_path_query_array(label, '$.*') )
      = jsonb_array_length( jsonb_path_query_array(label, '$.* ? (@ >= "")') )
  )
);
```

Though, I would be remiss not to mention that perhaps this type of checking should be done at the application layer, or that maybe you should consider storing information in a type constrained column rather than a jsonb object column.

A schema such as the one below would allow you to ensure type adherence using more robust and less arcane magic.

```
CREATE TABLE test_labels (
  label_id integer primary key
, label_key text
, label_value text
)
```